# Using fgets for multiple lines with stdin

Tags: c, while-loop, fgets, pointer-arithmetic

I'm new to C programming, and I'm trying to store multiple lines from `stdin` into an array. I succeeded in storing each line in the array, but it doesn't append the new lines but just store it over the current content of the array.

I don't know how to specify that it should append the lines at the end of the current content of the array. Could someone show me how to proceed?
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char line[150];

while (fgets(line,20,stdin) != NULL){

}
printf("%s",line);
```

stdin:

```
Hi
 tv
truck
```

What it's currently printing:

```
truck
```

What I want to print but don't know how to append the lines:

```
Hi
 tv
truck
```

The content of `line` should be:

```
[H,i,\n,' ',t,v,\n,t,r,u,c,k]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like the following

```
size_t n = 0;

while ( fgets( line + n,20,stdin) != NULL)
{
    n += strlen( line + n );
}
```

If you need to remove the last new line character '\n' then after the loop you can add the following statement

```
if ( line[n-1] == '\n' ) line[n-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: At the same time you should probably use something like `sizeof line - n` instead of the hardcoded `20`.